# How to structure grpc request(s) with a combination of multiple large files and some other fields

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I am new to grpc and trying to implement a service which should have a provision to take parameters similar to following:

1. param 1
2. param 2
3. large file 1 - preferably stream
4. large file 2 - preferably stream

From my understanding so far, it cannot be done as a single rpc method. I have to split into different methods - say one unary method to take in param 1 and param 2 and another method that takes in a file as a stream. But then I have to maintain state across two rpc calls because logically it is one call from a client perspective. Is that the right way to implement this scenario? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful for you to provide more details as to what you're trying to do.

It's sometimes useful to model gRPC as if there were no remote (no network) and you're invoking any-old methods|functions.

Let's assume you're doing a file upload:

```
fn uploader(name: string, content: []byte) -> bool {}
```

This is a (synchronous) unary method that takes the name of the file and some (arbitrarily-sized) content.

Its implementation may be:

```
fn uploader(name: string, content: []byte) -> bool {
  content.as_chunks()
    .map(|c| upload_chunk(name, c.start, c.data))
    .reduce(|resp| ... )
}
```

> **NOTE** `upload_chunk` closes over `name` because this method needs to track which file(name) is being uploaded.

The implementation also uses a synchronous unary method (`upload_chunk`). Each time it's called, we await the reply before proceeding. We need to do something with all the replies too.

An alternative (and potentially more efficient) implementation is to `upload_chunk` asynchronously; we don't await on each reply. Conventionally, we would gather futures from each `upload_chunk` and manage them. Alternatively, we could delegate this to some other mechanism to do it for us. We create some channel|stream, we pump data onto it and then we close it:

```
fn uploader(name: string, content: []byte) -> bool {
  let s = Stream::new()
  content.as_chunks().range(|c| s.upload_chunk(name, c.start, c.data))
  s.close()
}
```

> **NOTE** I'm assuming `s.chunk()` is non-blocking and that `s.close()` returns  success or failure.

Hopefully this shows that, while the client may think it's making one call (`uploader`), whichever approach you take will require potentially multiple calls and, whichever approach you take unary or streaming or both, can be implemented using gRPC.